# when function expression to declare class how can I define type?

Tags: typescript, function, class, function-expression

```js
const Foo: new () => any = class {
  constructor() {}
  bar(): string {
    return ‘Hello World!’;
  }
};
const instance = new Foo();
```

below I want to replace any cause my config not allows any

new () => any

How can I define Foo()'s result ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest defining an interface named `Foo` to correspond to the instances that the  class expression named `Foo` creates:

```
interface Foo {
  bar(): string;
}
```

Then you can declare `Foo` as type `new () => Foo`:

```
const Foo: new () => Foo = class {
  constructor() { }
  bar(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
};
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyARnFABQCUAXMgM5hSgDmA3AQL4Hf4LogM0mWiAgB3ZFWQBeAHxCs05AgA2cOnRwEifAYwCuCMOgqUcyLoRJkqtBkxDMtVolAhh9UEMgDkACQgVFSwAdRMVABMAQh92K0sOVmQCXUFQBjgQJBlkUQkMdCo4oA)

Comment: inferface Foo {} can represents the class's instance type? then thanks a lot :)